# Where can I post questions related to cameras?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am not able to find a place where I can ask questions regarding cameras and photography. On which Stack Exchange site can I post my questions regarding cameras and photography?

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 9):

[Photography SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/faq) sounds like your best bet:

> What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Photography - Stack Exchange is for professional, enthusiast and amateur photographers.
>
> If you have a question about …
>
> - photography
> - photographic processing or retouching
> - using photographic equipment
> - techniques and best practices
>
> and it is **not** about ...
>
> - videography
> - Which camera or brand is the "best"
> - Graphic Design
> - Programming
> - Web Site Development
> - Image Manipulation (outside of the Photography context)
>
> … then you're in the right place to ask your question!

Answer (score 2):

As [Rory](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145262/172936) said, [Photography.SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/faq) sounds like the best bet.  That said, before posting your question there, you should take a look at the existing posts and [FAQ](https://photo.stackexchange.com/faq) to make sure that you are indeed on the right site.

You say your question is about photography and cameras but if your question is

> "Which camera or brand is the best"

Then you might want to reconsider posting it.

Reading the faq is a **must** but even more important is to gauge the site and its community, see how they operate and only jump in when you are confident that you are posting an **on topic and constrictive question** that has the **possibility to help future visitors**.

---

As a side note you'll be able to find a list of Stack Exchange sites on the Stack Exchange website -

https://stackexchange.com/sites

There's also some links in the footers of all SE sites...